# Сериализация и Десериализация класса

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Есть такой класс и методы сериализации\десериализации в нем

```
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string Name;
    public string Login;
    public string Password;
}
[Serializable]
public class Datas
{
    private List<Data> DataList = new List<Data>();
    //количество запросов в нашем списке
    public int Count()
    {
        return DataList.Count;
    }
    //индексация списка
    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return this[index]; }
        set { this[index] = value; }
    }
    //цепляем один конкретный запрос, если он нам нужен
    public Data ReturnDatas(int i)
    {
        return DataList.ElementAt(i);
    }
    //добавляем запрос в список
    public void AddData(Data data)
    {
        DataList.Add(data);
    }
    //удаляем запрос из списка
    public void RemoveData(Data data)
    {
        DataList.Remove(data);
    }
    //сохраняем с помощью сериализации
    public void SaveListOfDatas(string path)
    {
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Data>));
        xmls.Serialize(filestream, DataList);
        filestream.Close();
    }
    //загружаем с помощью сериализации
    public void LoadListOfDatas(string path)
    {
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Data>));
        DataList = (List<Data>)xmls.Deserialize(filestream);
        filestream.Close();
    }
    //ищем конкретный запрос среди всех
    public Data FindDAtaInList(string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DataList.ElementAt(i).Name == name)
            {
                return DataList.ElementAt(i);
            }

            if (DataList.ElementAt(i).Login == name)
            {
                return DataList.ElementAt(i);
            }
            if (DataList.ElementAt(i).Password == name)
            {
                return DataList.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Использование

```
private void saveasxmlToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var allnames = names.ToArray(); //массив имен из коллекции Label
        var alllogins = logins.ToArray(); //массив логинов из коллекции TextBox
        var allpasswords = passwords.ToArray(); //массив паролей из коллекции TextBox

        Data data = new Data();

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < allnames.Length; i1++)
        {
            Label name = allnames[i1];
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
            {
                data.Name = names[i].Text;
            }
        }

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < alllogins.Length; i2++)
        {
            TextBox login = alllogins[i2];
            for (int i = 0; i < logins.Count; i++)
            {
                data.Login = login.Text;
            }
        }

        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < allpasswords.Length; i3++)
        {
            TextBox password = allpasswords[i3];
            for (int i = 0; i < passwords.Count; i++)
            {
                data.Password = password.Text;
            }
        }

        list.AddData(data);
        list.SaveListOfDatas("file.xml");
    }
```

На выходе же получается файл в котором сериализован только последний член массива.
Массивы получаются из коллекций контролов, которые динамически добавляются на форму.
Что я делаю не так, если десериализация и добавление значений контролов на форму производится вполне правильно(ну почти)?

```
private void backupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.LoadListOfDatas("file.xml");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            names[i].Text = list.ReturnDatas(i).Name;
            logins[i].Text = list.ReturnDatas(i).Login;
            passwords[i].Text = list.ReturnDatas(i).Password;
        }
    }
```

Если XML файл имеет например такой вид, данные возвращаются в контролы формы

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ArrayOfData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Data>
        <Name>1</Name>
        <Login>123</Login>
        <Password>qwe</Password>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Name>1</Name>
        <Login>123</Login>
        <Password>qwe</Password>
      </Data>
      <Data>
        <Name>1</Name>
        <Login>123</Login>
        <Password>qwe</Password>
      </Data>
    </ArrayOfData>
```

Но при сериализации получается только один экземпляр

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>
    <Name>unnamed</Name>
    <Login />
    <Password />
  </Data>
</ArrayOfData>
```

Что я делаю не так? Подскажите.

Comment: Вы создаёте и заносите в список один-единственный экземпляр `Data data = new Data();`

Comment: Угу. Попробуйте продублировать эту строку `list.AddData(data);` хотя бы ещё раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Все оказалось просто.

```
 var allnames = names.ToList(); //массив имен из коллекции Label
 var alllogins = logins.ToList(); //массив логинов из коллекции TextBox
 var allpasswords = passwords.ToList(); //массив паролей из коллекции TextBox
                   
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.Name = names[i].Text;
            data.Login = logins[i].Text;
            data.Password = passwords[i].Text;
            list.AddData(data);
        }
        list.SaveListOfDatas("file.xml");
```